# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: table is not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate, derby, glassfish-4

I have example web application Hibernate 4.3.5 + Derby database 10.10.1.1+ Glassfish4.0 with IDE NetBeans 8.0Beta.

I have the next exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: CUSTOMERV is not mapped
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:189)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:109)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:95)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:331)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3633)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3522)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:562)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
... 72 more
```

**Form from index.xhtml**

```
<h:panelGrid id="panel1" columns="2" border="1"
                 cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Add Customer Information"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputLabel value="First Name:"/>
        <h:inputText value="#{customer.firstName}" id="fn"/>
        <h:outputLabel value="Last Name:"/>
        <h:inputText value="#{customer.lastName}" id="ln"/>
        <h:outputLabel value="Email:"/>
        <h:inputText value="#{customer.email}" id="eml"/>
        <h:outputLabel value="Date of Birth:"/>
        <h:inputText value="#{customer.sd}" id="s"/>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <h:outputLabel value="#{customer.msg}" id="msg" styleClass="msg"/>
            <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{customer.saveCustomer}">
            </h:commandButton>
        </f:facet>
    </h:panelGrid>
```

**Customer.java**

```
    package com.javaknowledge.entity;

    import com.javaknowledge.dao.CustomerDao;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
    import javax.persistence.*;    

    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped

    public class Customer implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer custId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private Date dob;
    private String sd, msg, selectedname;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");


    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String email, Date dob) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getSd() {
        return sd;
    }

    public void setSd(String sd) {
        this.sd = sd;
    }

    public Integer getCustId() {
        return this.custId;
    }

    public void setCustId(Integer custId) {
        this.custId = custId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name = "DOB")
    public Date getDob() {
        return this.dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getSelectedname() {
        return selectedname;
    }

    public void setSelectedname(String selectedname) {
        this.selectedname = selectedname;
    }

    public void saveCustomer() {
        try {
            Date d = sdf.parse(sd);
            System.out.println(d);
            this.dob = d;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CustomerDao dao = new CustomerDao();
        dao.addCustomer(this);
        this.msg = "Member Info Saved Successfull!";
        clearAll();
    }
    public void updateCustomer() {
        try {
            Date d = sdf.parse(sd);
            System.out.println(d);
            this.dob = d;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CustomerDao dao = new CustomerDao();
        dao.updateCustomer(this);
        this.msg = "Member Info Update Successfull!";
        clearAll();
    }
    public void deleteCustomer() {
        CustomerDao dao = new CustomerDao();
        dao.deleteCustomer(custId);
        this.msg = "Member Info Delete Successfull!";
        clearAll();
    }

    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
        List<Customer> users = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        CustomerDao dao = new CustomerDao();
        users = dao.getAllCustomers();
        return users;
    }

    public void fullInfo() {
        CustomerDao dao = new CustomerDao();
        List<Customer> lc = dao.getCustomerById(selectedname);
        System.out.println(lc.get(0).firstName);
        this.custId = lc.get(0).custId;
        this.firstName = lc.get(0).firstName;
        this.lastName = lc.get(0).lastName;
        this.email = lc.get(0).email;
        this.dob = lc.get(0).dob;
        this.sd = sdf.format(dob);
    }

    private void clearAll() {
        this.firstName = "";
        this.lastName = "";
        this.sd = "";
        this.email = "";
        this.custId=0;
    }

   }
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/derbyDB</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">user1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <property name="c3p0.min_size">1</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_size">5</property>
    <property name="c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>

    <mapping class="com.javaknowledge.entity.Customer" resource="com/javaknowledge/entity/Customer.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Customer.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.javaknowledge.entity.Customer" table="CUSTOMERV" schema="APP">
        <id name="custId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="cust_id" />
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="firstName" type="string">
            <column name="first_name" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastName" type="string">
            <column name="last_name" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="email" type="string">
            <column name="email" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="dob" type="date">
            <column name="dob" length="10" not-null="true" />
        </property>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Either you use NativeSQL or make sure to use the name of variable and tablename as classname if using JPQL.

Comment: If using JPQL then you use Class name and not table name otherwise this error can come.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Finally I found a mistake! Hope this is useful to someone. When doing a request to the database(in my case it Apache Derby), name of base need write the first letter upper case other in lower case.

This is wrong query:

```
session.createQuery("select first_name from CUSTOMERV").
```

This is valid query

```
session.createQuery("select first_name from Customerv").
```

And class entity must be same name as database, but I'm not sure.

Comment: That may not be the reason. Select c from Customer c this is fine query as Customer is you class name and we should write class name in the query not the table name.Another thing in your hibernate.cfg.xml you have given both <mapping resource and class> only one would be fine. Please check with that.

Comment: Great, the single thing that worked for me was just using the class name well formatted rather than the database table name itself. I think Hibernate requires this to be able to do a proper mapping. It's a little confusing and not the usual way like with JDBC though, but i hope future versions try to like into this issue. It would be a plus to keep some style from JDBC for some of these query mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. Actually it takes the entity/class name not the table name. For example : if your table name is CUSTOMER and your entity name is Customer, It will take Customer in the query as it is an HQL query.

Answer (score 88):

in **HQL** query, Don't write the **Table name**, write your **Entity class name** in your query like

```
String s = "from Entity_class name";
query qry = session.createUqery(s);
```

Answer (score 44):

In my case I just forgot to add `nativeQuery = true`

```
@Query( value = "some sql query ...", nativeQuery = true)
```

For Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA

Answer (score 24):

If you are using the JPA annotations to create the entities and then make sure that the table name is mapped along with @Table annotation instead of @Entity.

Incorrectly mapped :

```
@Entity(name="DB_TABLE_NAME")
public class DbTableName implements Serializable {
   ....
   ....
}
```

Correctly mapped entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DB_TABLE_NAME")
public class DbTableName implements Serializable {
   ....
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 16):

hibernate.cfg.xml file should have the mapping for the tables like below. Check if it is missing in your file.

```
......
<hibernate-configuration>
......
......
  <session-factory>
......
<mapping class="com.test.bean.dbBean.testTableHibernate"/>
......
 </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
.....
```

Comment: this was the case for me, while changing implementation to work with Oracle DB instead of Derby - with Derby, for some reason, declaring entities in persistence.xml was not necessary (it seemed logical to me, since entities were already annotated) (maybe that was because of an older driver (ojdbc6))

Answer (score 8):

None of the other solution worked for me.

Even if I don't think its the best practice, I Had to **add it into the code** like this

`configuration.addAnnotatedClass(com.myOrg.entities.Person.class);`

here

```
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(com.myOrg.entities.Person.class);

    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In Hibernate,

```
session.createQuery("select first_name from Customerv").
```

The `Customerv` is your **Entity Name**, not your **Table Name**

Answer (score 5):

May be this will make it more clear, and of course makes sense too.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")

/**
 * 
 * @author Ram Srinvasan
 * Use class name in NamedQuery
 * Use table name in NamedNativeQuery
 */
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "findUserByName", query = "from User u where u.name= :name") })

@NamedNativeQueries({ @NamedNativeQuery(name = "findUserByNameNativeSQL", query = "select * from users u where u.name= :name", resultClass = User.class) })
public class User implements Principal {
...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is one more chance to get this exception even we used class name i.e., if we have two classes with same name in different packages. we'll get this problem.

I think hibernate may get ambiguity and throws this exception, so the solution is to use complete qualified name(like **com.test.Customerv**)

I added this answer that will help in scenario as I mentioned. I got the same scenario got stuck for some time.

Answer (score 5):

It means your table is not mapped to the JPA.
Either Name of the table is wrong (Maybe case sensitive), or you need to put an entry in the XML file.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: in which xml file?

Comment: @SubrahmanyamJanapamula  - if u are using springboot and JPA , no need of any xml file mappings

Answer (score 5):

I too have faced similar issue when i started to work on Hibernate. All in all i can say is in the createQuery one needs to pass the name of the entity class not the table name to which the entity is mapped to.

Answer (score 4):

Other persons that are using mapping classes for Hibernate, make sure that have addressed correctly to *model* package in `sessionFactory` bean declaration in the following part:

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mblog.model"></property>
```

Comment: I had this issue with micronaut when I forgot to change `packages-to-scan` in my `application.yml` config file.

Answer (score 3):

In my case: spring boot 2 ,multiple datasource(default and custom). `entityManager.createQuery` go wrong: 'entity is not mapped'

while debug, i find out that the entityManager's unitName is wrong(should be custom,but the fact is default)
the right way:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "customer1") // !important, 
private EntityManager em;
```

the `customer1` is from the second datasource config class:

```
@Bean(name = "customer1EntityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("customer1DataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.xxx.customer1Datasource.model")
            .persistenceUnit("customer1")
            // PersistenceUnit injects an EntityManagerFactory, and PersistenceContext
            // injects an EntityManager.
            // It's generally better to use PersistenceContext unless you really need to
            // manage the EntityManager lifecycle manually.
            // 【4】
            .properties(jpaProperties.getHibernateProperties(new HibernateSettings())).build();
}
```

Then,the entityManager is right.

But, em.persist(entity) doesn't work,and the transaction doesn't work.

Another important point is:

```
@Transactional("customer1TransactionManager") // !important
public Trade findNewestByJdpModified() {
    //test persist,working right!
    Trade t = new Trade();
    em.persist(t);
    log.info("t.id" + t.getSysTradeId());

    //test transactional, working right!
    int a = 3/0;
}
```

`customer1TransactionManager` is from the second datasource config class:

```
@Bean(name = "customer1TransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
        @Qualifier("customer1EntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}
```

The whole second datasource config class is :

```
package com.lichendt.shops.sync;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateSettings;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "customer1EntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "customer1TransactionManager",
        // 【1】这里写的是DAO层的路径 ，如果你的DAO放在 com.xx.DAO下面，则这里写成 com.xx.DAO
        basePackages = { "com.lichendt.customer1Datasource.dao" })
public class Custom1DBConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JpaProperties jpaProperties;

    @Bean(name = "customer1DatasourceProperties")
    @Qualifier("customer1DatasourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "customer1.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties customer1DataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "customer1DataSource")
    @Qualifier("customer1DatasourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "customer1.datasource") //
    // 【2】datasource配置的前缀，对应上面 【mysql的yaml配置】
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        // return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        return customer1DataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "customer1EntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("customer1DataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.lichendt.customer1Datasource.model") // 【3】这里是实体类的包路径
                .persistenceUnit("customer1")
                // PersistenceUnit injects an EntityManagerFactory, and PersistenceContext
                // injects an EntityManager.
                // It's generally better to use PersistenceContext unless you really need to
                // manage the EntityManager lifecycle manually.
                // 【4】
                .properties(jpaProperties.getHibernateProperties(new HibernateSettings())).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "customer1TransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("customer1EntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Comment: shows how to config multiple datasource with springboot 2.

Answer (score 2):

If you by any chance using java for configuration, you may need to check the below `bean` declaration if you have package level changes. Eg: `com.abc.spring` package changed to `com.bbc.spring`

```
@Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {

        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource());
        //builder.scanPackages("com.abc.spring");    //Comment this line as this package no longer valid.
        builder.scanPackages("com.bbc.spring");
        builder.addProperties(getHibernationProperties());

        return builder.buildSessionFactory();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Should use Entity class name for em.createQuery method
or
Should use em.createNativeQuery method for native query without entity class

**With Entity class:**

*em.createQuery("select first_name from CUSTOMERV")*

**Without Entity class or Native query:**

*em.createNativeQuery("select c.first_name from CUSTOMERV c")*

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that worked:

The data access object that actually throwed this exception is

```
public List<Foo> findAll() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from foo").list();
}
```

The mistake I did in the above snippet is that I have used the table name foo inside createQuery. Instead, I got to use Foo, the actual class name.

```
public List<Foo> findAll() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Foo").list();
```

Thanks to this blog: https://www.arundhaj.com/blog/querysyntaxexception-not-mapped.html

Answer (score 2):

Other persons that are using mapping classes for Hibernate, make sure that have addressed correctly to model package in sessionFactory bean declaration in the following part:

```
public List<Book> list() {
    List<Book> list=SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from book").list();
    return list;
}
```

The mistake I did in the above snippet is that I have used the table name foo inside createQuery. Instead, I got to use Foo, the actual class name.

```
public List<Book> list() {                                                                               
    List<Book> list=SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Book").list();
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add parameter nativeQuery = true

ex:

```
@Query(value="Update user set user_name =:user_name,password =:password where user_id =:user_id",nativeQuery = true)
```

Answer (score 2):

in my case was that i forgot the "nativeQuery = true"

Answer (score 1):

In Apache Derby DB, refrain from using table names as "user" or so because they are reserved keywords on Apache Derby but will work fine on MySql.

In the Query, you must specify the name of the Entity class that you want to fetch the data from in the FROM clause of the Query.

```
List<User> users=session.createQuery("from User").list();
```

Here, User is the name of my Java Entity class(Consider the casing of the name as in Java it matters.)

Answer (score 0):

Problem partially was solved. Besides creating jdbc/resource(DB Derby) had to create JDBC Connection Pool for db resource in Glassfish admin console, and check it on pinging. Now all CRUD operation work just fine. I check, object Customer in database adding properly, update and delete too. But in Glassfish output log have same exception:

```
SEVERE:   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: CUSTOMERV is not mapped [select concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as name from CUSTOMERV]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:234)
    .......

Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: CUSTOMERV is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:109)
```

Comment: Suggest open a new question... this is not an answer to the first question... or enhance your first question with 'Update' keyword

Answer (score 0):

The mistake in my case is that I used `session.createQuery()` instead of `session.createSQLQuery()`