# Problem with query custom using spring boot

Tags: mysql, ajax, spring-boot

I'm trying to make a custom query but the table name is not mapped. Thi is the code, can you help me please?

```
@Query("FROM sbootuserss WHERE age > 17")
```

This is the error:

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: sbootuserss is not mapped

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: table is not mapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23018836/org-hibernate-hql-internal-ast-querysyntaxexception-table-is-not-mapped)

Answer (score 1):

Do you also have a model with the appropriate annotation in your application?

```
 @Table(name = "sbootuserss")
 public class Sbootuserss implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

   // another fields ... 
 }
```

And the query:

```
 @Query("FROM Sbootuserss WHERE age > 17")
```